# OpenGL: How to make light to be independent of rotation?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, shader, lighting

I have a diffuse lighting shader which seems to work when the object is not rotating. However, when I apply rotation transform, the light also seems to rotate along with the object. It's like the object and the light stay still but the camera is the one that moves around the object.

Here's my vertex shader code:

```
#version 110

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightSource;

attribute vec3 vertex;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelviewMatrix * vec4( vertex, 1.0 );

    vec3 N = gl_NormalMatrix * normalize( normal );
    vec4 V = modelviewMatrix * vec4( vertex, 1.0 );
    vec3 L = normalize( lightSource - V.xyz );

    float NdotL = max( 0.0, dot( N, L ) );

    gl_FrontColor = vec4( gl_Color.xyz * NdotL, 1.0 );

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

and here's the code that does the rotation:

```
scene.LoadIdentity();
scene.Translate( 0.0f, -5.0f, -20.0f );
scene.Rotate( angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
object->Draw();
```

I sent the eye-space light position through a glUniform3f, inside the object->Draw() function. The light position is static, and defined as:

```
glm::vec4 lightPos( light.x, light.y, light.z, 1.0 );
glm::vec4 lightEyePos = modelviewMatrix * lightPos;
glUniform3f( uniforms.lightSource, lightEyePos.x, lightEyePos.y, lightEyePos.z );
```

What's wrong with this approach?

Edit: The glm::lookAt code

```
Scene scene;
scene.LoadMatrix( projection );
scene.SetMatrixMode( Scene::Modelview );
scene.LoadIdentity();
scene.SetViewMatrix( glm::lookAt( glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), glm::vec3( 0.0f, -5.0f, -20.0f ), glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) ) );
```

The SetViewMatrix code:

```
void Scene::SetViewMatrix( const glm::mat4 &matrix ) {
    viewMatrix = matrix;
    TransformMatrix( matrix );
}
```

Then I just changed the modelviewMatrix I used to the viewMatrix:

```
glm::vec4 lightPos( light.x, light.y, light.z, 1.0 );
glm::vec4 lightEyePos = viewMatrix * lightPos;
glUniform3f( uniforms.lightSource, lightEyePos.x, lightEyePos.y, lightEyePos.z );
```

Comment: My guess is that your eye-space light position is incorrect. How are you generating this?

Comment: I sure hope that's the case. Here's how I did it: glm::vec4 lightPos( light.x, light.y, light.z, 1.0 );
glm::vec4 lightEyePos = modelviewMatrix * lightPos;
glUniform3f( uniforms.lightSource, lightEyePos.x, lightEyePos.y, lightEyePos.z );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Statement 1: The light position is static.
>
> Statement 2: `lightEyePos = modelviewMatrix * lightPos;`

These two claims are inconsistent. If your light position is supposed to be static, you shouldn't be applying a rotated model matrix to it.

If your lightPos is defined in world coordinates, then you should multiply it with the `viewMatrix` not the `modelviewMatrix`. The modelviewMatrix contains the model matrix, which contains the model's rotation (you don't want to apply this to a fixed light source).

Comment: Ah I didn't know you could separate them. I'll try your suggestion and see how it works.

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't work. I took the view matrix created by glm::lookAt function and used that to multiply the light position. Is that correct? Since I never really modified the camera position, I also tried sending just the light position values without the transformation but it's still the same.

Comment: @JackyBoen: I would have expected the glm::lookAt matrix to be what you need to use. If this is not working, can you clearly describe what new result you're getting, and put all your updated code (using lookAt as the view matrix) in an appended edit in your original post? Don't bother trying to use the raw light coordinates in the shader, it won't work unless you do all of the lighting equations in world space.

Comment: Alright, I updated my post with the code. The result I'm getting is that the light still seems to rotate with the sphere (my object is a sphere). So it kind of looks like the moon phase transition.

Comment: @JackyBoen Hmm, sorry I can't see why it's not working. I'm still quite sure my advice was correct (and it seems more than a few people agree), but I can't explain why it's not rotating correctly, unless there's something else going on in code that I can't see.

Comment: I see. Then I guess I messed it up somewhere in my code. Thanks for the help! At least I know the correct implementation now :)